# Why does augmenting the covariance matrix with additional data not improve out of sample prediction?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, high-dimensional

I was thinking about the structure of high dimensional regression models, and there are essentially two statistical steps, estimating covariance matrix of the data, and estimating the individual correlations between the features and response. Imagine a situation in which you have a whole bunch of unlabeled data, many features, and not very many measurements of the outcome. (One might imagine a real life example being a genomics company that has a lot of genomics data, but not a lot of associated and labeled health data).

It seems that one solution would be to use the extra unlabeled data that you have (assuming it is drawn from the same distribution) to better estimate the covariance matrix of your features, and then use that covariance matrix to fit a linear model. At the limit, I'm imagining replacing the sample covariance matrix with the true covariance matrix--this seems reasonable to me and feels like it could be theoretically justifiable (though I haven't yet worked out any real theory on this). However, when I do a quick and dirty numerical test with artificial data, it doesn't work at all.

I've included a minimal example in the python code below. I generate a dataset of 1000 observations of 100 features where the features are not independent (this is achieved by multiplying in the matrix cov_op). I then create a response vector with a little bit of noise using a randomly drawn coefficient vector. I split off 200 datapoints as my real training set, compare RMSE of three different procedures. First, I do standard linear regression with the smaller 200 point dataset. Next, I do linear regression as before, but I replace the sample covariance matrix generated by the smaller dataset with the "population" covariance matrix (may not precisely be population, but I don't think I'm wrong in making that analogy). Finally, I compare this to the performance of linear regression fit to the entire dataset to see how these compare to the optimal least squares solution.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(40)
X_orig=np.random.randn(1000,100)
cov_op=np.random.randn(100,100)
X=X_orig@cov_op/50
beta_true=np.random.randn(100)
y=X@beta_true+np.random.randn(1000)
eps=0
X_sub=X[:200]
y_sub=y[:200]

beta_sub=np.linalg.inv(X_sub.T@X_sub+eps*np.identity(100))@X_sub.T@y_sub
beta_extra=np.linalg.inv(X.T@X/(1000/200)+eps*np.identity(100))@X_sub.T@y_sub
beta_opt=np.linalg.inv(X.T@X+eps*np.identity(100))@X.T@y

print(np.sqrt(np.mean((X@beta_sub-y)**2)))
print(np.sqrt(np.mean((X@beta_extra-y)**2)))
print(np.sqrt(np.mean((X@beta_opt-y)**2)))
```

With the following results:

```
1.322868364093136
1.5638143652272147
0.9798055421298206
```

While I set the random seed to 40 here, the ordinary regression tends to do better very consistency.

It seems somewhat obvious to me that more accurately estimating the covariance matrix will lead to better  out of sample predictions. This, however, seems to be false here, so what am I missing?